# jQuery close button not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I have absolutely no access to a machine with IE on it right now - I was wondering if someone could look at my jQuery for the following URL and help me diagnose the "issue" thats happening - the "close" button should fadeOut the parent of anywhere it is located, but obviously there seems to be an issue

(click one of the menu items to see the larger image):

http://eatatcarlos.com/en/menu

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your actual code here.

Comment: remove any "console.log" statements. If developer tools are not up, IE will throw an exception. "Console is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `console.log` statements in your JavaScript code. IE chokes on them.